Describing the boundary of the feasible direction cone to a convex open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ at a boundary point: connection via subdifferential?
Let $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a convex, open set with nonempty boundary. Let $x_0\in \partial{U}.$ We can describe $U$ locally near $x_0$ as a super level set of a suitable continuous concave function $G(x_1\dots x_n):=x_n-\gamma(x_1\dots x_{n-1})$, where $\gamma:\mathbb{R}^{n-1}\to \mathbb{R}, \gamma(0)=x_0$ as follows (see Evans' PDE book, appendix)
An open set $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is $C^0$ if for each point $x_0 \in \partial U$, there exist $r > 0$ and a $C^0$ function $\gamma: \mathbb{R}^{n-1} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that - upon relabeling and reorienting the coordinates axes if necessary - we have
$$\Omega \cap B(x_0,r) = \left\{ x \in B(x_0,r): x_n > \gamma(x_1,...,x_{n-1}) \right\}.$$
$$\partial\Omega \cap B(x_0,r) = \left\{ x \in B(x_0,r): x_n = \gamma(x_1,...,x_{n-1}) 
\right\}.$$
I'm looking at the feasible direction cone at $x,$ which is defined by:
$$F_{x_0}(\bar{U}):=\{v\in \mathbb{R}^n: \exists t_v>0: x_0+tv \in U\forall 0 < t < t_v\}$$
When $U$ is convex, it can be rewritten as:
$$F_{x_0}(\bar{U}):=\{v\in \mathbb{R}^n: \exists t>0: x_0+tv \in U\} = \{\lambda(z-x_0):z\in U, \lambda >0\}.$$
Question: How to describe the topological boundary $\partial{F_{x_0}(U)}$ using the function $\gamma$ or $G$ above? When $x_0$ is a $C^1$ boundary point, $\gamma, G$ above are  $C^1, {F_{x_0}(U)}=\{z\in \mathbb{R}^n: z\cdot \nabla{G}(x_0) > 0\} \implies \partial{F_{x_0}(U)}=\{z\in \mathbb{R}^n: z\cdot \nabla{G}(x_0) = 0\}$. So in this case, we have a description of $\partial{F_{x_0}(U)}$ using the gradient of $G,$ whose super level set is $U.$
Assume now that $\gamma$ or equivalently, $G$ is merely continuous at $0.$ I'd guess that here that the boundary $\partial{F_{x_0}(U)}$ can be described using the boundary of the normal cone of the subdifferential of  $-F,$ (that's convex) at $x_0?$ I'm really not sure though, as I've almost zero knowledge in convex geometry or optimization, that study these objects. But it seems like it's indeed the case, as here
$\partial{F_{x_0}(U)}=\{z\in \mathbb{R}^n: z\cdot \nabla{G}(x_0) = 0\}$ = boundary of the normal cone of $-\nabla{F}$ at $x_0.$
If you could please at least refer me to the right resources, theorems or books/notes etc, I'd be grateful! Thank you.
Relevant question: link.
